# Creating JavaScript variable within PHP retrieving in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, database

Basically what I have is, there is an index file, that links to a JS file, which then pulls in a PHP file.

So in the PHP file I have (along with other code) :

```
echo " <script type='text/javascript'>var paging = [ ";
echo "{";
echo "numrows:'" . number_format($numrows) . "',";
echo "pagenum:'" . number_format($pagenum) . "',";
echo "maxpage:'" . number_format($maxpage) . "',";
echo "record_min:'" . number_format($record_min) . "',";
echo "record_max:'" . number_format($record_max) . "'";
echo "}];</script>";
```

Then, in a JS file I use ajax:

```
req.open("GET", "server.php", true);
```

and within the readystatechange I need to retrieve that paging variable you see from the php file because it contains data from the database.

In the JS file I have tried using a variable instead of echo

```
var m=<?PHP echo $paging; ?>
```

but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestions or ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: This question was already asked many times here. Please search for similar questions before you post one.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use JSON instead of JS. You should be able to pass a PHP array to the json_encode function. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Also, on the PHP side, you may want to modify your response headers to indicate that the response message body is JSON:

```
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
```

Then, use jQuery to get the JSON from the server: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to use jQuery to get the JSON just for that... There is JSON2.js that adds JSON support to old browsers and that's about all you need.

Comment: Well, jQuery is useful for other things too. But yes, if he has no use for the other parts of the library, perhaps a specialized library would be better. I'd still use jQuery anyways. Chances are, you'll run into another use case where jQuery will be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution for you if you don't get direct JSON working (scaled down to two variables)

```
echo '<div id = "numrows">'. number_format($numrows) . '</div>';
echo '<div id = "pagenum">'. number_format($pagenum) . '</div>';
```

in the php file

```
req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
        document.getElementById('return').innerHTML = req.responseText;
    }
}
req.open("GET", "server.php", true);
req.send();
n["numrows"] = document.getElementById("numrows").innerHTML;
e = document.getElementByID("numrows");
e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
n["pagenum"] = document.getElementById("pagenum").innerHTML;
e = document.getElementByID("pagenum");
e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
```

in the javascript

```
<div id = "return" style="display: none;"></div>
```

in the html

Not the most elegant solution, but fairly straightforward to follow if  you can't get anything else working.

Answer (score -2):

Ok because jQuery makes this easy, here is my example:

```
$paging = array(
                "numrows" => number_format($numrows),
                "pagenum" => number_format($pagenum),
                "maxpage" => number_format($maxpage),
                "record_min" => number_format($record_min),
                "record_max" => number_format($record_max)
               );

$output = json_encode($paging);

header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );

echo $output;
```

Then in your javascript page using jquery do this:

```
function myCallBackFunction(data){
    alert(data.numrows);
}
$.getJSON('server.php',myCallBackFunction(data));
```

Hope this helps.

**Edited to use array and json_encode**

Comment: it's much easier to use json_encode, do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This would get you lots of parse errors... Plus it is NOT JSON. The value of a property should be encased in " not in '. There sould not be a ; at the end of a JSON string

Comment: yes its easier to use json_encode but I was quickly using his code.

Comment: what? how come I got another downvote after I updated the answer? this question has not been marked as answered yet and my suggestion is as good as any solution?